# Adding a new Migration File using Rake (in the command line)

Tags: sql, command-line, migration, rake

I know there's a way to automatically create the barebones of a migration file by entering some rake command in the command line but I can't seem to remember exactly what it is. I know it should look *something* like this...

```
rake db:create NAME=table_name
```

but that keeps failing. I also tried

```
rake db:create_migration NAME=table_name
```

but no luck with this either. The first attempt returns "Don't know how to build task 'table_name' and the second says "Don't know how to build task 'migration'

Answer (score 0):

`rake` isn't the command for this, instead you can either:

- manually create the file
- run `rails generate migration table_name` in a rails app
- or in my case where I'm not using rails, `pliny-generate migration table_name`